# Cannot logout in Unity

Tags: unity, logout

When I logout, I can change accounts, but the account I have logged out remains logged in after changing to another account. Both accounts are then logged in, the check-mark appears next to both in the drop-down menu at the upper right of the screen.

I can force a logout with `pkill`. I have also found that logging in and then out of a guest session will logout all users - strange!

My question: what is wrong, and how do I fix it?
Thanks!

Edit: Perhaps I should add that I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and that logging out worked fine until yesterday.
Additionally, I had a window manager issue (no menu bars) which I fixed with `setsid unity`. Afterwards, the logout problem started.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 similar glitch.  Use:

```
sudo rm ~rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove # to remove previous obsolete packages. 
sudo reboot
```

No problems since 1 1/2 years ago.